# Couldn't import messages to primary channel in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I followed this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams#request-post-a-message-with-inline-image) step by step to import messages in a channel to a new team

Things were going well, but **I have a problem when I tried to import messages to a primary channel in a new created team**.

The API responded success when I imported a message to a primary channel.

```
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170/channels/19:4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57@thread.tacv2/messages
METHOD: POST
REQ_BODY: {
  "createdDateTime": "2023-04-14T03:27:43.499Z",
  "importance": "normal",
  "from": {
    "user": {
      "id": "3aa4fc7d-c1b0-4f85-a72c-ca5c9057ef3d",
      "displayName": "CAT",
      "email": "CAT@synologycat.onmicrosoft.com",
      "userIdentityType": "aadUser",
      "tenantId": "dcb0e1d1-6cde-4420-a658-ede52a8bead1"
    }
  },
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "\u003cdiv\u003e\n\u003cdiv itemprop=\"copy-paste-block\"\u003e\n\n\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:14px\"\u003e一般的文字\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003c/div\u003e"
  }
}
RES_STATUS: 201
RES_BODY: {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170')/channels('19%3A4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57%40thread.tacv2')/messages/$entity","id":"1681442863499","replyToId":null,"etag":"0","messageType":"message","createdDateTime":"2023-04-14T03:27:43.499Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","lastEditedDateTime":null,"deletedDateTime":null,"subject":null,"summary":null,"chatId":null,"importance":"normal","locale":"en-us","webUrl":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19%3A4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57%40thread.tacv2/1681442863499?groupId=61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170&tenantId=dcb0e1d1-6cde-4420-a658-ede52a8bead1&createdTime=1681442863499&parentMessageId=1681442863499","policyViolation":null,"eventDetail":null,"from":{"application":null,"device":null,"user":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.teamworkUserIdentity","id":"3aa4fc7d-c1b0-4f85-a72c-ca5c9057ef3d","displayName":"CAT","userIdentityType":"aadUser"}},"body":{"contentType":"html","content":"<div>\n\n<div itemprop=\"copy-paste-block\">\n\n\n<div style=\"font-size:14px\">\u4e00\u822c\u7684\u6587\u5b57</div>\n</div>\n</div>"},"channelIdentity":{"teamId":"61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170","channelId":"19:4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57@thread.tacv2"},"attachments":[],"mentions":[],"reactions":[]}
```

But when I listed messages in the channel after finishing migration, **I saw null content with the uploaded message.**

I expect the responded content of the message is the same as what I imported.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170/channels/19:4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57@thread.tacv2/messages
{
  "id": "1681442863499",
  "replyToId": null,
  "etag": "1681442863499",
  "messageType": "message",
  "createdDateTime": "2023-04-14T03:27:43.499Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-04-14T03:27:43.499Z",
  "lastEditedDateTime": null,
  "deletedDateTime": "2023-04-14T03:27:43.499Z",
  "subject": null,
  "summary": null,
  "chatId": null,
  "importance": "normal",
  "locale": "en-us",
  "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19%3A4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57%40thread.tacv2/1681442863499?groupId=61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170&tenantId=dcb0e1d1-6cde-4420-a658-ede52a8bead1&createdTime=1681442863499&parentMessageId=1681442863499",
  "from": null,
  "policyViolation": null,
  "eventDetail": null,
  "body": {
    "contentType": "text",
    "content": null
  },
  "channelIdentity": {
    "teamId": "61826bbc-4b7d-48f7-a5aa-ba8d82756170",
    "channelId": "19:4f99689e8f904f65bff4f68b55976d57@thread.tacv2"
  },
  "attachments": [
    
  ],
  "mentions": [
    
  ],
  "reactions": [
    
  ]
},
```

This weird behavior only happens when I import messages to a primary channel. It's ok if I import messages to a new created channel.

I would be appreciate if someone can tell me how to sovle the problem, thank you.

Comment: This could be because the primary channel comes by default and won't be in migration mode. We create a channel in channelCreationMode for import purpose. We will confirm internally and get back to you.

Comment: We tried this at our end it is working fine. Message got imported and it shows content in list messages call for general channel - https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Wzt.png

Comment: Could you please share the complete payload with us, also please verify the timestamp specified on messages during import was one that is later than the timestamp of creation of channel given during channel creation. Thanks.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Thank you for your hint. I succeed in importing messages to primary channel. I suggest that the note should be added in document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Meghana-MSFT

> please verify the timestamp specified on messages during import was
> one that is later than the timestamp of creation of channel

It works.
Be noted that the create time of the primary channel can't be [patched](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-patch?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the create time is the same as   the create time of the team, and you can create a team with speicifed createdDateTime in migration mode.